# Finding a prime factorization close to a particular number...

Tags: number-theory, functions, optimization, prime-factorization

If we are given a prime $p$, naturals $y$ and $N$ such that $p^y$ is approximately equal to $N$, there are some statistics I'm looking for.  If we take some of the factors in the prime factorization of $p^y - 1$, how close can we get to $\sqrt{N}$ by forming a product of some of the factors?

Let me give an example.  Say $p=3$, $y=5$, and $N = 240$.  We have $p^y = 3^5 = 243 \approx N$.  Now, we can factor $3^5-1 = 242 = 2 \cdot 11^2$.  We can take $2 \cdot 11 = 22$ from these factors, and compared to $\sqrt{240} = 15.4919$ is off by around $7$.  This $22$ is our *best fit*.

Now, we hopefully can create a function that gives the average "best fit" for a particular $p$, $y$, and $N$.  What is this function?

Essentially, what I'm looking for is how close we get to $p^{y/2}$, by taking some factors from the prime factorization of $p^y - 1$.

We are allowed to substitute all primes between $q$ and $q^2$ in place of $p$.  Hopefully this will give a much better bounds!

Comment: I think a better (and almost equivalent) way of stating this would be: For $N=p^y-1$, how close can one of the factors of $N$ be to $\sqrt{N}$? Still, this probably needs to be clarified further. Are you asking for the best case? The average case? The worst case? Something else?

Comment: @URL:  So really what I'm after is the worst case, but technically I can do this several times for varying $p$.  I didn't want to make the question to hard to answer.  I'm trying to get the error close to a factor of $\log{N}$.

Comment: In general, the error can be terrible. Consider $p=1009$, $y=5$, for example. $p^y-1$ turns out to factorice as $2^4\times3^7\times7\times1037517185381$, which makes it pretty much impossible to get close to $p^\frac{y}{2}$. The same will happen whenever $\frac{p^y-1}{p-1}$ is prime, which one can reasonably conjecture (lest one wanted to disprove a weaker version of Bunyakovsky) to happen infinitely many times for prime $y$.

Comment: @URL:  I've changed the question so that one can use all primes between $q$ and $q^2$ (for a given $y$ such that $q^y \approx N$).